# Creating the following json object from a jquery array of menu items and submenu items

Tags: jquery

I have a context menu which has menu items and sub menu items.
A menu can have zero or more  sub menu items.I need to map my menu object to a json object as follows. How can I do it?

```
            var commonMenuItems = [
              {
                  Menu: "Print",
                  Caption: "Print"


                  },
                  SubMenuItems: [
                    {
                        SubMenuItemName: "PrintSelected",
                        SubMenuItemDisplayName: "Print Selected",

                    },
                    {
                        SubMenuItemName: "PrintAll",
                        SubMenuItemDisplayName: "Print All",

                    }
                ]
              }

        ];
```

I want to map commonMenuItems array to items json object items programatically.

```
  items: {
                "Print": {"name": "Print"
                  "items":{
                       "PrintSelected": {"name": "Print Selected"},
                       "PrintAll": {"name": "Print All"},
                  }
}
```

Comment: I am looking at pure jquery answer. No Server side code involved

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsonSerializer. There are many available.JSON.NET and ServiceStack.NET serializers are better options but I recommend you ServiceStack Serializer from NuGet Package.It is the fastest serializer on the planet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are returning commonMenuItems at client then converting it to javascript array `var commonMenuItems = datagotfromserver;` then to convert it to json you can simply use  `var items = JSON.stringify(commonMenuItems);`.